# How to Compile all C file into Object and place it in subdirectories

Tags: c, linux, makefile

How to compile all C files into object files and place them in subdirectories?

I have three directories:

1. `usr` - where main.c is located
2. `sources1` - where init_var1.c and init_var2.c are located
3. `include` - where the header files are located
4. `obj` - this directory should contain the object files made from the C source files in directories listed under 1 and 2.

I wrote this `Makefile`:

```
CC=gcc

O_DIR = ./../obj
I_DIR = ./../include

SOURCES := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

OBJECTS := $(addprefix $(O_DIR)/,$(OBJECTS))

all: $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) -c -I$(I_DIR) $< -o $@
```

but the output is

```
make[1]: enter directory «/home/alexey/exercise/ex_makefile/source»
gcc -c -I./../include init_var1.c -o ../obj/init_var1.o
gcc -c -I./../include init_var1.c -o ../obj/init_var2.o
make[1]: out from directory «/home/alexey/exercise/ex_makefile/source»
```

However, I need

```
make[1]: enter directory «/home/alexey/exercise/ex_makefile/source»
gcc -c -I./../include init_var1.c -o ../obj/init_var1.o
gcc -c -I./../include init_var2.c -o ../obj/init_var2.o
make[1]: out from directory «/home/alexey/exercise/ex_makefile/source»
```

Please help, how can this be done?

Comment: You should set the localization to default (e.g. `export LANG=C LC_ALL=C` ....) before posting output. Not everyone here is able to read Russian error messages.

Comment: @dkasak not the same, i wont to compile difference .c file but i compile identity.

Comment: Yes, I noticed now, sorry.

Comment: I'm missing how the desired output differs from the actual.

Comment: @JohnBollinger i always compile init_var1.c but i need to compile init_var1.c and init_var2.c

Comment: `$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)` rule is suspect.

Comment: You seem to be relying in features specific to GNU make.  Is that intentional, or at least acceptable, so that using more GNU-isms will also be acceptable?

Comment: @jxh why? can u explain please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `SOURCES` to equal the wildcard expansion of `*.c`. This expands to a list of all your .c files and therefore, the line

```
$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
```

expands to something like

```
a.o b.o c.o ... : a.c b.c c.c ...
```

Note that this is wrong semantically since each of your object files shouldn't depend on *all* the source files.

Since the [automatic variable `$<`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#index-_003c-_0028automatic-variable_0029) denotes the name of the *first* prerequisite, each of the object files `a.o`, `b.o`, `c.o` and so forth gets created using the source file `a.c`.

---

What you want instead is a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html):

> You define an implicit rule by writing a pattern rule. A pattern rule looks like an ordinary rule, except that its target contains the character ‘%’ (exactly one of them). The target is considered a pattern for matching file names; the ‘%’ can match any nonempty substring, while other characters match only themselves.

This will allow you to make each of your object files depend only on their corresponding source file (and it will also make `$<` expand to the correct file since the first prerequisite will be the *only* prerequisite). Therefore, your rule should look like this:

```
%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c -I$(I_DIR) $< -o $(O_DIR)/$@
```

In fact, the [examples page for pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Examples.html#Pattern-Rule-Examples) of the GNU make manual has an example very similar to your rule.

Comment: Yes, except that the pattern rule you've presented is not correct for the OP's requirement of building targets from sources residing in a different directory.